# Choosing a random value from a nested dict and updating it in another nested dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm currently coding an RPG Text Game in python and I'm trying create random encounter system on every boot. I have a dict with multiple encounters and their corresponding categories and another nested dict which contains the information about the area of the game. I can create a random selection and have it printed out, but how do I get that random selection to update in every "interact" in the area nested table. I want a new random value from the encounters table for each "interact" key in the area nested dict.

Also I only need the values to be updated so `"interact" : "zombie"` for example, categories are just for the weighted random selection as I want them to be "random-ish" with most of them being nothing ("") or enemy

Though this is the latest version as I've tried lots of different approaches and they all fail - Also this code below errors out and I have no idea how to solve this problem. If needed I can also post all my other attempts.

Here is my failed attempt:

```
import random

encounters = {
    "enemy" : {
        1 : "zombie",
        2 : "wolf",
        3 : "wraith"
    },

    "chest" : {
        1 : "chest",
        2 : "weapons_chest",
    },

    "npc"   : {
        1 : "villager",
    },

    "furniture" : {
        1 : "bed"
    },

    "nothing"   : {
        1 : ""
    }
}

area = {

    "spawner" : {

        "spawn" : {
            "name"      : "Spawn",
            "interact"  : "",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "alleyway_1"
            }
        }
    },

    "alley" : {

        "alleyway_1"   : {
            "name"      : "Alleyway 1",
            "interact"  : "",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "spawn",
                2   : "alleyway_2",
                3   : "hall"
            }
        },

        "alleyway_2"   : {
            "name"      : "Alleyway 2",
            "interact"  : "",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "alleyway_1"
            }
        }
    }
}

def random_encounters():
    print("random encounters")

    weights_a = [0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5]

    encounter_a = random.choices(encounters, weights_a)
    encounter_b = random.choice(list(encounter_a.values()))

    for q, w in area.items():
        for a, s in area[w].items():
            area[w][s]["interact"] = encounter_b

random_encounters()
```

EDIT:

Expected result would be:

```
 area = {

    "spawner" : {

        "spawn" : {
            "name"      : "Spawn",
            "interact"  : "bed",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "alleyway_1"
            }
        }
    },

    "alley" : {

        "alleyway_1"   : {
            "name"      : "Alleyway 1",
            "interact"  : "zombie",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "spawn",
                2   : "alleyway_2",
                3   : "hall"
            }
        },

        "alleyway_2"   : {
            "name"      : "Alleyway 2",
            "interact"  : "chest",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "alleyway_1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `"interact" : "zombie"` zombie is the output from `random_encounters()`

Comment: Can you add an expected output?

Comment: @Merig added expected result somewhat its hard to explain, I just need the random_encounter function to write a value into area[x][y]["interact"] by choosing a random value from encounters by first picking a random category from encounters and then random value in encounters then that value is what is being updated to area[x][y]["interact"] where X and Y are corresponding keys for the nested dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `random.choices` and `random.choice` only works with list type, you can get the list of object keys and pick one of them randomly instead. The resulting key selected will be used to access the sub dictionary items. One more thing, when iterating through the dictionary using `for key, values in dictionary.items()`, the first variable will be the dictionary key and the other one will be the value corresponding to that key. I think you're confusing the order of the two so I also fixed that for you.

I also added the `import json` and `print(json.dumps(area, indent=2))` so you can verify that it is what you want. You can delete it after you're done testing.

**Edit:**
In order to set unique encounters for different area, you put the random encounter generating code inside the 2 for loops so that each area will have its own random encounter.
Also, since you want to set the each items have a certain probability to occur and using `list(encounters.keys())` will give a list of dictionary's keys in random order, I decided to change from using `list(encounters.keys())` to using `encounters_keys=["enemy", "chest", "npc", "furniture", "nothing"]` that have the `encounters`' keys in the same order of the `weights_a` so that each type of encounter have a correct probability.

```
import random
import json

encounters = {
    "enemy" : {
        1 : "zombie",
        2 : "wolf",
        3 : "wraith"
    },

    "chest" : {
        1 : "chest",
        2 : "weapons_chest",
    },

    "npc"   : {
        1 : "villager",
    },

    "furniture" : {
        1 : "bed"
    },

    "nothing"   : {
        1 : ""
    }
}

area = {

    "spawner" : {

        "spawn" : {
            "name"      : "Spawn",
            "interact"  : "",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "alleyway_1"
            }
        }
    },

    "alley" : {

        "alleyway_1"   : {
            "name"      : "Alleyway 1",
            "interact"  : "",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "spawn",
                2   : "alleyway_2",
                3   : "hall"
            }
        },

        "alleyway_2"   : {
            "name"      : "Alleyway 2",
            "interact"  : "",
            "solved"    : False,
            "connects"  : {
                1   : "alleyway_1"
            }
        }
    }
}
def random_encounters():
    print("random encounters")
    encounters_keys = ["enemy", "chest", "npc", "furniture", "nothing"]
    weights_a = [0.3, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.5]

    for q, w in area.items():
        for a, s in area[q].items():
            encounter_a = random.choices(encounters_keys, weights_a)[0]
            encounter_b = random.choice(list(encounters[encounter_a].keys()))
            area[q][a]["interact"] = encounters[encounter_a][encounter_b]

    print(json.dumps(area, indent=2))

random_encounters()
```

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, but not entirely I want the function to loop so that each individual "interact" gets a new random value from encounters if that makes sense. The input is exactly what I want but each interact needs its own unique value. (See my edit if it explains it better)

Comment: Can some areas have similar encounters or all of them have to have unique encounters?

Comment: Can be the same, but the "randomness" of it is determined by the probability of "weights_a" so if there's a 0.3 probability of it being an "enemy" there can be more than one enemy and another randomizer for which enemy it is, again it's 1/3 for it to be a zombie (because there's 3 keys in "enemy") therefore yes there can be multiple zombies as long as all "interact" isn't the same. I hope I explained it well

Comment: OK I have updated the code so that each area have its random encounter. You can test out a few times to check if certain encounters like ("enemy" or "nothing") will take place more often than the rest, indicating the weights were taken into consideration.

Comment: THAT is perfect! Exactly what I needed. I'm gonna study your code now and learn where I've went wrong. Thank you so so much :)

Comment: No problem. Glad I can help :)